# Laravel composer breaks when moving a view file

Tags: view, laravel-5, composer-php

More of a 'wonder why' than something broken since I can leave files where they currently are.

In my main view, I @include a header view. the header  view file resides in the same directory as my main view.  I have a composer set up to load an array variable with data when the header view is called.  And it works great.

However, if I move my header to a partials folder located in the same directory as the main, and change the @include to point to the new location, when I run the application, it tells me I have an undefined variable in the header file.

I have looked through what code I code find (or more remember where was) and I dont see anything that specifically references paths for the view in the composer.

Is there somewhere I need to look to specifically tell the composers where the view is located?

Comment: How about you write a ViewComposer for your header or simply load the variables from a config file?

Comment: Did you also update your View composer to be for "partials.header" and not just "header"?

Comment: Also, never just "wonder why". If something isn't working the way you want it to, make it :D